# Transforming automated text to a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a set of computer-generated notices saved in a text file - it looks like this:

> - MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123456 **for** $10000.99 **for** the month of 2023 02 (FEB)
> - MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123457 for $100.01 for the month of 2022 09 (SEP)
> - MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123458 for -$51.00 for the month of 2022 10 (OCT)

*Ideal Output - as DataFrame*

| Statement | Amount | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 10000.99 | 2023 02 (FEB) |
| 123457 | 100.01 | 2022 09 (SEP) |
| 123458 | -51 | 2022 10 (OCT) |

I know I can turn this into a CSV outside of Python, then import it with pandas.

But can I load the text file into Python as-is, and transform convert it into a DataFrame?

One "hint" - the word **for** can work as my column separator in this case.  It splits every row reliably into the fields I want.  It's a bit of luck.

Comment: probably want to use something like `s = pd.read_csv(sep = your delimiter)`, and then use `s.str.split('for',expand=True)`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What do you need help with exactly? Like, what have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Do you know how to use [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)? Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: On second though, rather than treat it like a weird CSV, it'd be better to apply a regex on each line.

Comment: @Justin Sharber, how should look like your dataframe ? Can you add your expected output to the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of your expected dataframe *is not clear* but here is an option with [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
df = (
        pd.read_csv("input2.txt", header=None, sep="|").squeeze()
            .str.extract("(.*): Statement# (.*) for (.*) for the month of (\d+) (\d+) \((\w+)\)")
            .set_axis(["company_name", "statement", "amount", "year", "month_number", "month_name"], axis=1)
      )
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
     company_name statement     amount  year month_number  month_name
0  MY COMPANY LLC    123456  $10000.99  2023           02         FEB
1  MY COMPANY LLC    123457    $100.01  2022           09         SEP
2  MY COMPANY LLC    123458    -$51.00  2022           10         OCT
```

Answer (score 1):

Input file:

```
MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123456 for $10000.99 for the month of 2023 02 (FEB)
MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123457 for $100.01 for the month of 2022 09 (SEP)
MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123458 for -$51.00 for the month of 2022 10 (OCT)
```

Read in the text file using `readlines()` and load the resulting list of lines into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    df = pd.DataFrame(lines)  

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0  MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123456 for $10000.9...
1  MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123457 for $100.01 ...
2  MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123458 for -$51.00 ...
```

If you need to remove the `for` strings from the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data.append(line.strip().split('for'))

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                    0            1                            2
0  MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123456    $10000.99    the month of 2023 02 (FEB)
1  MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123457      $100.01    the month of 2022 09 (SEP)
2  MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# 123458      -$51.00    the month of 2022 10 (OCT)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `' for '` *as* the separator.
- Remove extraneous terms with `str.replace()`.

---

```
## Load data
cols = ['Check', 'Amount', 'Month', ]
df = pd.read_csv(input.txt, sep=' for ',
                names=cols, 
                engine='python').dropna()

## Remove extraneous terms
badTerms = [
    'MY COMPANY LLC: Statement# ', 
    'the month of ',
    ]
for col in df.columns:
    for term in badTerms:
        df[col] = df[col].str.replace(term, '',
                                     regex=False)
```